Unable to edit network style after import of xgmml network
I am attempting to pull networks from several different sessions into a new session with layouts and formatting for publication purposes. I exported the relevant networks as *.xgmml files (with style data) and imported them into a new session. The first network works fine, but all subsequent imported networks appear to have fixed style formatting. Importing into existing or as new network collections doesn't seem to help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please give more information and context around your problem. What program are you trying to import these networks into [I doubt it is tximport, because that is for raw gene count information]? Can you please show the first few lines of the .xgmml files so that we can understand the format better?
